# Observable error while trying to connect with end point restAPI

Tags: angular, rest

employee.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'
import {HttpClient,HttpClientModule} from'@angular/common/http/http'
import { Employee } from './employee';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  private apiServerUrl = '';
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  
  public getEmployee(): Observable<Employee[]>{
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/employee/all);
  }
}
```

Employee.ts

```js
export interface Employee{
    id:number;
    name:string;
    email:string;
    jobTitle:string;
    phone:string;
    imageUrl:string;
    employeeCode:string;

}
```

When I try to return

```js
public getEmployee(): Observable<Employee[]>{
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/employee/all);
  }
```

getting this error.
Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<Employee[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Employee[]>'.
Type 'HttpEvent<Employee[]>' is not assignable to type 'Employee[]'.
Type 'HttpSentEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'Employee[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2322)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to put the closing ` symbol of end of the string interpolation.

Comment: Yes. Damn that little symbol. Error gone. Thank you.